# border-image slow to load

Tags: html, css

The image that I use in border-image doesn't load promptly. Sometimes it takes several seconds to load, sometimes it doesn't load at all, and sometimes it loads just fine, right away. The image itself is only 3 or 4kb, 401 * 211, png. How can I solve this problem?

```
<div style="border-style:solid;
border-width:43px 54px 54px 27px;
-moz-border-image:url(../img_peripheral/window_mac_2.png) 43 54 54 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image:url(../img_peripheral/window_mac_2.png) 43 54 54 27 repeat;
-o-border-image:url(../img_peripheral/window_mac_2.png) 43 54 54 27 repeat;
border-image:url(../img_peripheral/window_mac_2.png) 43 54 54 27 fill repeat;
text-align:justify;color:#666666;font-size:small;font-family:monospace;">

XXXXX

</div>
```

Comment: Does it exhibit this behavior when loaded directly?

Comment: I think it doesn't occur when the image is loaded directly.